# Repositing labels in Feynman diagram

Tags: feynmf, feynmp

I have the following code in `Feynmf`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi
\usepackage{empheq}  

\begin{document}

\unitlength = 2mm
\begin{fmffile}{vert2}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,40)

\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{i3}
\fmf{photon,label=$\mathbf{a}$}{i3,v1}
\fmf{fermion,label=$\mathbf{b}$,l.side=right}{i1,v2}
\fmf{fermion,label=$\mathbf{c}$}{v3,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v3}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmf{photon}{v4,v2}
\fmfblob{.12w}{v4}
\fmfdot{v1,v2,v3}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

Now I would like to reposition the labels $a,b,c$ such that they are closer to the vertices. Furthermore, I would like to shorten all three incoming lines. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

- To shorten the "incoming" lines, increase the tension, so that the "incoming" line pulls as hard as the two other lines coming into the vertex
- To move the labels, put them on the vertices rather than the lines, using `\fmfv` instead of `\fmfdot`.  If you want to position the labels away from the vertices, then you can adjust `label.angle` and `label.dist` until you get them right.

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
 \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi
\usepackage{empheq}  

\begin{document}

\unitlength = 2mm
\begin{fmffile}{vert2}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,40)

\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{i3}
\fmf{photon,tension=2}{i3,v1}
\fmf{fermion,tension=2}{i1,v2}
\fmf{fermion,tension=2}{v3,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v3}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmf{photon}{v4,v2}
\fmfblob{.12w}{v4}
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=2thick,label=$\mathbf{a}$,label.angle=-60}{v1}
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=2thick,label=$\mathbf{b}$,label.angle=-60}{v2}
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=2thick,label=$\mathbf{c}$,label.angle=60}{v3}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

To get better placed labels, you could try something like this:

```
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=2thick,
    label=$\mathbf{a}$,label.angle=20,label.dist=1cm}{v1}
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=2thick,
    label=$\mathbf{b}$,label.angle=-150,label.dist=8mm}{v2}
\fmfv{decor.shape=circle,decor.filled=full,decor.size=2thick,
    label=$\mathbf{c}$,label.angle=108,label.dist=8mm}{v3}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I would like the labels to not be positioned at the vertices, but rather slightly away from them. (Because in the real figure I want to make there are also some labels at the internal lines, so it might get confusing.) Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think Torsten Ohl ever implemented labels part way along a line, which is what you want, so there's no clean way to do it. I'll edit the answer with some ideas.

Comment: I see that the [manual](http://www.pd.infn.it/TeX/doc/latex/feynmf/manual.pdf#page=16) says in Table 2 on page 16: “label.pos – relative position of the label (not implemented yet!)” You may want to consider TikZ-Feynman, which is a very modern (2016) package for drawing Feynman diagrams.